# Structures as attributes

Tags: c++

These are the attributes of my class:

```
    class Addition_Struct: public Addition {
    // attributes
    struct a {
        int element;
        struct a *next;
    };
    struct b {
        int element;
        struct b *next;
    };
    struct outcome {
        int element;
        struct outcome *next;
    };
    struct a a_data;
    struct b b_data;
    struct outcome outcome_data;
// methods
a convertToStackA(int); // everything is right with this line
```

How can I call them from inside the .cpp file? Using `this->a` syntax returns "type name is not allowed". Using `a*` as method's return value displays "Identifier is not allowed", and "Declaration is incompatible with...".

.cpp file:

```
a* Addition_Struct::convertToStackA(int number)
{
   // identifier "a" is undefined, and declaration is incompatible
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to address your new information. See it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
class Addition_Struct: public Addition {
// attributes
    typedef struct a {
        int element;
        struct a *next;
    } a;
};
```

Only defines a type named `Addition_Struct::a`. There is no member `a` for you to access with `this-a`. Remove the `typedef` to get the member you want.

**EDIT**

The method definition you provided is not inline (it's outside the class definition). Therefore, you must use a fully scoped type name for the return type.

```
Addition_Struct::a* Addition_Struct::convertToStackA(int number)
{

}
```

since the compiler sees the type `Addition_Struct::a` but not the type `a`.

Answer (score 1):

From within the class you can just use `a`. From outside the class use the fully qualified name `Addition_Struct::a`.

Btw since this is C++ you can just use

```
struct a {
    int element;
    a *next;
};
```

without the typedef.

Comment: +1 for commenting that the typedef isn't necessary. I take it so much for granted that I forgot to mention it.

Comment: So there's no any way to call this structure with "this" identifier?

Comment: @user2252786, not the **type name** `a`. If you declare a member of that type in the class then it will of course be accessible through `this`.

Comment: I see now, thank you. Though there appeared some more problems. I can't use "a*"/"a" datatype as method's return value. It still says identifier is undefined.

Comment: Edited, I corrected attributes as was said here, and added method's definition/declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In you example you only declared structures, so your Addition_Struct have 3 structures defined, but no data members. You need to add something like

```
a a_data;
b b_data;
outcome outcome_data;
```

after structure declarations, to be able access data members like:

```
this->a_data;
this->b_data;
this->outcome_data;
```

Comment: Yes, but a_data etc. are pointers to the first list's elements.